# Identify network adapter only with MAC Address

Tags: networking, adapter, ethernet, mac-address

Is it possible that to identify a network adapter by only its MAC Adress?

I know that it is possible to find out the vendor, but i need the exact Name/Description, e.g. "Intel Ethernet I217-LM".

**Update (more info):**

Let's say I have 10 MAC addresses. I want to paste them into a (online) tool that gives me then name of the adapter.

Is this even possible? The 6 first digits are vendor specific, I know that but, is there any other scheme?

Comment: Need some more info...do you want to retrieve this programmatically, if so, what language?  Os specific or independent?

Comment: my bad, let's say i have 10 MAC adresses. I want to paste them into a tool (online) that gives me then name of the adapter. Is that even possible? The 6 first digits are vendor specific, i know that but, is there any other scheme?

Comment: Not reliably...mac addresses can be cloned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the MAC Address is simply a unique Identifier for each network adapter. You can think of it as a unique random number coded directly into the networking hardware, so that it can never change. You can figure out the vendor, because "blocks" of MAC addresses are assigned to each vendor, in order to ensure that no one gets a card with a duplicate address. To which models the addresses are assigned is up to the vendor, and it is highly unlikely that a vendor will publish such a list.

In order to obtain the information you need, you will have to use a OS/Programming language specific function. If you can tell us what environment you are working on, maybe someone can help you figure out how to get the information.

Comment: i thank you for this information, this is all i needed.
Just wanted to know if there is a further scheme. There are different OSs that i have to find out and i only wanted  to do it with MAC Adress, so i don't have to sit in front of every computer. Thank you very much.